# Warning: mssql_query(): message: Invalid object name 'Consignment'. (severity 16)

Tags: php, html, sql-server-2008, slim

I need your guidance. i created an API in slim framework with mssql and php. It was working ok but now it display an error when i check on postman. i have attached error screenshot below. please help me out .

```
    $app->post('/tracking', function ($request) use ($app){
        $params_tracking = $request->getBody();
        $params_tracking = json_decode($params_tracking);

    global $connTrack;
    $consignment = $params_tracking->data;
     $strsql = <<<SQL
       SELECT 
          c.consignmentNumber,
          c.pieces,
          c.consigner,
          c.consignee consignee,
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), c.bookingDate, 105) bookingDate,
          c.weight,
          c.serviceTypeName,
          r.receivedBy ReceivedBy,
          case when cth.reason is null then ( CASE WHEN r.CurrentStatus IS 
           NULL THEN s.TrackingStatus ELSE r.CurrentStatus END )
            else cth.reason end CurrentStatus,
            DeliveryTime,bb.name Destination,c.consignerAccountNo 
             AccoutNo,b.name orign,r.delievryRider delievryRider
            FROM Consignment c
            INNER JOIN Branches bb ON c.destination = bb.branchCode
             INNER JOIN Branches b ON c.orgin = b.branchCode
              LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT rc.consignmentNumber,
                              max(rc.receivedBy) ReceivedBy,
                              max(rc.Status) CurrentStatus,
                              max(rc.deliveryDate) DeliveryTime,
                              max(r.firstName + ' (' + rrs.riderCode + ' )') 
                  delievryRider
                  FROM   RunsheetConsignment rc,
                              Riders r,
                              RiderRunsheet rrs,
                              ExpressCenters ec
                     WHERE  rc.runsheetNumber = rrs.runsheetNumber
                              AND rrs.riderCode = r.riderCode
                              AND rrs.expIdTemp = r.expressCenterId
                              AND rrs.expIdTemp = ec.expressCenterCode
                              AND ec.bid = rc.branchcode
                    GROUP BY  rc.consignmentNumber
                        ) r
                     ON c.consignmentnumber = r.consignmentNumber
                      INNER JOIN (
                      SELECT MAX(t.id) ID,t.consignmentNumber 
                     FROM ConsignmentsTrackingHistory t
                      GROUP BY t.consignmentNumber
                     )
                     ct ON ct.consignmentNumber = c.consignmentNumber
                    INNER JOIN ConsignmentsTrackingHistory AS cth
                    ON cth.id = ct.ID
                    INNER JOIN MNP_ConsginmentTrackingStatus AS s
                    ON s.StatusID = cth.stateID
                     WHERE c.consignmentNumber = '$consignment' and 
                     c.consignerAccountNo not in 

                        ('4B45','7240','4H86','4H87',                
                        '4H88','4B87','7240','4B45','4H91',
                        '4H89','4H90','4F47');
                         SQL;

                 $result_track = mssql_query( $strsql,$connTrack );
                $num_rows = mssql_num_rows($result_track);

                 if ($num_rows > 0){
                  while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result_track)){
                   $track = array();     //create the array 
                $tracking_array['cn_no']         = $consignment;  
                $tracking_array['book_date']     = $row['bookingDate'];  
                $tracking_array['service_type']  = $row['serviceTypeName'];  
        $tracking_array['origin']        = $row['orign']; 
        $tracking_array['destination']   = $row['Destination']; 
        $tracking_array['status']        = $row['CurrentStatus'];
        $tracking_array['delivery_date'] = $row['DeliveryTime'];
        $tracking_array['received_by']   = $row['ReceivedBy'];                              
        array_push($track,$tracking_array);  
                    }
              echo json_encode($track);
              }
           });
```

[image: Errors screenshot]

Comment: where i use mysql? the query based on sql server, i have used mssql every where.